# List Dialog similar to Android L Notifications (Transparent ListView Divider?)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I have a dialog containing a dynamic ListView. I'm trying to style it similar to the Android L notifications center but I can't seem to do so.

My dialog window background is already transparent and the ListView content is set up but I can't seem to add transparent dividers to it. When I change my listview's divider color to transparent, it completely disappears removing the gap in between. After manually setting a divider height, it returns but it's not transparent. Instead, it's some sort of dark blue-ish transparent color.

My code for this is fairly simple:

```
    // Create ListView
    ListView mList = new ListView(context);
    mList.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // Create dialog base
    final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.TransparentDialog);
    mDialog.setContentView(mList);
    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);

    // Add listview content...
    // ...

    // Apply dividers and content
    mList.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(R.color.transparent));
    mList.setDividerHeight(72);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

.

How would I go on to styling it like it? My only issue with this is the lack of transparent ListView divider.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Android L Notifications]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up achieving this effect using card images with transparent margins embedded in them.

[image: My Layout]

Comment: can i have more informations about how you do that ? it's really interessting me ! thanks !

Comment: @ColombetJosselyn It's basically a basic custom Dialog with the window background and shadow removed. For spacing, I used 9-patch images with margins embedded inside instead of through code.